# Linear algebra MOOCs

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I am a statistics student studying a module of linear algebra at the undergrad level. I was looking for MOOCs that might help me. I tried saylor which meets my syllabus but I cannot find videos for it. I also tried MIT open coursware. They have two courses on this. The 18.700 meets my requirements but again I dont know why I cant find a link to get started on the course page. The others I found are based on standard reading. I have been a commerce student in high scholl and the notations confuse me so I really need a video based MOOC. Where can I start?

Comment: Have you looked at www.edx.org or www.coursera.org?

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation (although not a MOOC) has got to be [Khan Academy's Linear Algebra section](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra). Note that according to the site,

`this is an advanced course normally taken by science or engineering majors after taking at least two semesters of calculus (although calculus really isn't a prereq).`

Alternatively, if I could  recommend a book to you, [Linear Algebra Done Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582). What is especially nice about this book is summed up nicely on the linked page,

```
The author has taken unusual care to motivate concepts and to simplify proofs.
```